# Configuring the Jenkins Global properties through powershell

Tags: powershell, selenium, jenkins

I want to run automated selenium tests on different browsers and would like to pass the browser through as a parameter in my PowerShell script that triggers the tests to run.

The browser is currently determined by the value of my 'Browser' variable in the global properties in Jenkins.

Is there a way to assign the value from my PowerShell script to the 'Browser' global property value in Jenkins?

Comment: You can create parametrized job and pass _Browser_ as argument (if I understood you correct)

Comment: Yes you can, but I want this to be automated as well. The tests run overnight and currently I have to change the value for the browser manually. So I want it to override the value in the global properties.

Comment: Then try to use Jenkins Remote API for that